# Removing Commas from a parsed csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm parsing a big csv file and I need to know how to remove commas from the parsed csv.
I'm parsing it to html and I need like to know it there is a specific character at the line that was parsed but the document is full of commas, so it does not have a pattern, so how do I do it?
I tried this

```
for line_number,line in enumerate(csv_file):
line.strip(",")
if line_number < 6:
    continue
print(line)


csv_row = line.split("\t") 
print(csv_row)

for col_num,entry in enumerate(csv_row):
#information always start on line 6
    if len(entry) < 1:
        continue
    if entry[0] and  entry[1] and entry[2]  == "~":
        html_text += "<div class = 'child_entries'>" + entry + "</div>"
    if entry_count > 0:
        html_text += "</div>"    
    #elif entry[1] == "~":
     #   print("aaaa")
      #  html_text += "<div class = 'child_entries'>" + entry + "</div>"

    #if last_child_entry_column < col_num:
     #   html_text += '<div class="child_entries">'    

    html_text += '<div class="entry">'
    #last_child_entry_column = col_num
    entry_count +=1 

html_text += '<div>'  + entry + '</div>'
```

and tried using the `re` library and got

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

right now the parsed file looks like this

```
",,Description:a sequence of permission IDs from the backend global settings UserPermissions class.,,,,,,,,"
```

and the objective is like this

```
"Description:a sequence of permission IDs from the backend global settings UserPermissions class"
```

So, do you guys have any idea of how can I do it?

Comment: It seems like it's not actually parsed at all, so maybe start there. Python has a built in module named `csv` they may be of use.

Comment: try using `line.strip(',')`

Comment: I`m going to post all the code, line.strip didn`t work too

Comment: use `line = line.strip(',')`

Comment: better use module `csv` for this. It will care of commas and any other unexpected situations.

Comment: it`s a challenge @furas I can`t use any modules or libraries for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method "replace" of the class "str" doesn't manipulate the string in place, it returns the manipulated string. So what you need to do is save the result of that method call into a variable like follows:

```py
line = line.replace(",", "")
```

Comment: YOU ARE A GOD MAN, I LOVE YOUUUU, I`m debugging this code all night and I didn`t even think about that

Comment: sometimes the solution is easier than you think haha